# Codeigniter 2.2 failed create session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

I use CI 2.2 to build a simple login system. But I get problem when I try to generate session. Of course I have properly set up libraries (database, session) and User_M. When I retrieve data from database (without session), that's work fine. This is my Controller code:

```
public function verify()
{
    // Define variable
    $user = $this->input->post('username');
    $pass = $this->input->post('password');

    // Check input data
    if (!empty($user) AND !empty($pass))
    {
        // Check match data from db
        $checks = $this->User_M->check_user($user, $pass);

        if($checks->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            foreach ($checks->result() as $check)
            {
                $sess = array (
                    'username' => $check->username,
                    'logged_in' => TRUE
                );

                $rest = $this->session->set_userdata($sess);

                if ($rest)
                {
                    echo "working";
                } else {
                    echo "not working";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "Not found";
        }
    } else {
        echo "You've empty field";
    }
}
```

Additional explain, I check the result with `if ($rest)`...bla..bla..bla, that's echoing Not Working. Please let me know where's my mistakes?

Thank in advance

Comment: Have you loaded `SESSION` library before that..?

Comment: Of course I have properly set up, as you can see in my explanation

Comment: I didn't. I have used CI 2.1.4 before when build app, that's working fine without loading `session_start()`, I only use CI built in library

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with this statement

```
$rest = $this->session->set_userdata($sess);
```

the `set_userdata()` does not return anything, so according to your condition it will always execute the else part.

Try to change your condition like this

```
if (!empty($this->session->userdata("username"))){
   echo "Working";
}else{
   echo "Not Working";
}
```

Comment: I used `if (!empty($this->session->set_userdata('username')))` instead of `if (!empty($this->session->set_userdata[username]))`, but still doesn't work

Comment: My mistake, its `$this->session->userdata("username")`, I edited the answer.

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much. I make a littl modification in statement like this `if (!empty ($rest))` and I define variable `$rest = $this->session->userdata('username')`, now it's work fine :-)